# div not visible, even after adding display:block

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble hiding and showing a div once it gets to a certain page width - the idea is that at mobile sizes, I would take a div and switch it out for another one. Specifically, I'm using issuu to show sheet music, but for some reason it doesn't display when I want it to. It's clearly visible because it takes up space, but I can't see it for some reason. At 250% zoom on a macbook 13 inch it shows up as taking space, but is not actually visible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
            <div id="musiccontent">
            <div id="musicheader">
                Shades of Red (2012)
            </div>
                <div data-configid="11690692/7620748" style="width: 525px; height: 340px;" class="issuuembed"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//e.issuu.com/embed.js" async="true"></script>
                <div id="issuumobile">
                    <div data-configid="11690692/8138261" style="width: 320px; height: 207px;" class="issuumobile"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//e.issuu.com/embed.js" async="true"></script>
                </div>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src="music/Shades of Red.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
            <p>Recording from an informal reading by the UCSB Chamber Orchestra, conducted by Christopher Rountree.</p>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

normal display:

```
.issuuembed{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.issuumobile{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:none;
}
```

media query display:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
#images{display: none;}

body{
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

.eventtext{width: 75%; /* 400 / 1080px */}

.line{width:75%;}

table th:first-child, th:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(4){
    display: none;
}
table td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(4){
    display: none;
}

td{width:85%;}

#tablelist{display: none;}

.issuuembed{
    float: center;
    display:none !important;}

.issuumobile{
    float:center;
    display:block !important;
}
}
```

Website: http://cristinalord.com/shadesofred.html

Comment: The main issue you're having isn't that the "div" isn't showing, but the fact that nothing actually gets injected into the div

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, can you clarify what you mean when you say nothing gets injected? Thanks for responding!

Comment: If you inspect the code you see the script isn't being called. In the .isuuembed div the js script is injecting a bunch of html code. In the .isuumobile that code isn't there. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/TgxsLNn.png) is what I mean.

Comment: What I mean is, there is nothing to show within the div, which is why you see nothing

Comment: you need issuuembed class for script injection via their embed.js to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is taking up space because you set the width/height attributes

Second, I removed the `!important` as they seem to be taking precedence over many things.

```
.issuuembed{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:none
}

#issuumobile{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Third, you need the image to be placed inside the div to show/hide

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/bGNRY/2/)**

After your comments, I played with the HTML a bit more and changed this

```
<div id="issuumobile">
    <div data-configid="11690692/8138261" class="issuumobile"></div>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div id="issuumobile" data-configid="11690692/8138261" class="issuuembed"></div>
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/bGNRY/6/)

Comment: Works fine with a cat. Still doesn't seem to work with the .js script

Comment: I see.  Can we confirm that the id used is correct?

Comment: I see the second embed is nested in another `<div>` removing the nested div seems to make it work.  See updated demo

Comment: Yup seems good. Andyw was right catching that it needed to be issuuembed for both. Nice fix

Comment: note that "center" is not a valid value for the "float" attribute

Comment: hahaha, correct! I just copy/pasted his code - let me fix that

Comment: Yeah, not really you at fault, but best to keep people that don't know educated along the way :)

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the help! I've been taking some time to understand why you changed the css, and everything makes sense except for the change in the html. Could you explain why it's okay to combine the div in the way you did? Again, thank you! This is a great learning experience.

Comment: @dannav147 since the (original) parent `div` was used only as a container (i.e. it did not serve any other purpose) I felt it was unnecessary to have a `div` nested inside another `div` for styling purposes when you can reference it directly via an `id` attribute for CSS and the `class` attribute for `embed.js`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @blurfus thank you for the clarification! Makes perfect sense now that you say it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you only need to load `embed.js` once.

Secondly, you require `issuuembed` class.

So here's the solution

Note the new introduced classes `mobile-issuu` and `desktop-issuu`

So here's the default style

```
.desktop-issuu {
    width: 525px;
    height: 340px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.mobile-issuu {
    width: 320px;
    height: 207px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:none;
}
```

Here's the style applied with media query of `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`

```
.desktop-issuu {
    display:none;
}
.mobile-issuu {
    display:block;
}
```

The markup

```
<div data-configid="11690692/7620748" class="issuuembed desktop-issuu"></div>
<div class="mobile-issuu">
    <div data-configid="9032795/8168837" style="width: 320px; height: 207px;" class="issuuembed"></div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm now loading `embed.js` at the very end to make sure that DOM is ready before it tries to access the DOM.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/doiks14/bGNRY/8/)